# Filter gridview doesn't work when using Sqldataprovider

Tags: search, gridview, filter, yii2

Here's my modelSearch :

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = "select distinct number, 
                                  id, 
                                  write_date::date,
                                  customer_id,
                                  customer_name,
                                  sales.name,
                                  sales.id as sales_id  
                  from item 
                  inner join sales on sales.id = pa.sales_id
                  where status = 'oke' 
                  order by write_date::date
                 ";

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

this modelSearch work fine to load the data on the gridview, but fo the filtering it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: You have to give total count also `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html` check this for refrence

Comment: if you need  filter you should use your param for filter the query